# Is it a best practice to refactor an Interface method -- extracting a code fragment of a Interface method to create a new wrapping method?

Tags: c#

From MSDN, I got an example as follows:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
   return (IEnumerator) GetEnumerator();
}

public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator()
{
    return new PeopleEnum(_people);
}
```

Why did the author do like this? Is it a best practice?

--------EDIT---------

MSDN article link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx

Why didn't the author do as follows:

```
 IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 {
        return new PeopleEnum(_people);
 }
```

I tried,  it still works.

======= SECOND EDIT ==========

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace MyEnumerableEnumerator
{
    class Person
    {
        public Person(string name, int age)
        {
            Name = name;
            Age = age;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    class PeopleEnumerator : IEnumerator
    {
        int Position { get; set; }
        Person[] People { get; set; }
        int Length { get; set; }

        public PeopleEnumerator(Person[] people)
        {
            People = people;
            Position = -1;
            Length = people.Length;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            Position++;
            return Position < Length;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Position = -1;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    return People[Position];
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class People : IEnumerable
    {
        Person[] Persons { get; set; }

        public People(Person[] people)
        {
            Persons = new Person[people.Length];

            for (int x = 0; x < people.Length; x++)
                Persons[x] = people[x];
        }

        //public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        //{
        //    return new PeopleEnumerator(Persons);
        //}

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        private IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new PeopleEnumerator(Persons);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person[] persons = { new Person("Mark", 1), new Person("Siva", 2) };

            People people = new People(persons);

            foreach (Person person in people)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Age: {1}", person.Name, person.Age);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They did this because they wanted a custom iterator.  Please link the MSDN article

Comment: The link has been added. Thanks.

Comment: Down voting answers because you don't like them or you feel they don't completely answer your question is very bad form and doesn't encourage other people to answer your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They did as they did because they wanted a typed iterator for a non-generic collection.

**Edit**

foreach works since the compiler does some "magic"

Try this with your changed code:

```
        var enumerator = peopleList.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current.firstName); //compile error.
```

It will not compile, you have to cast the enumerator to PeopleEnum or change back the return type.

**Edit 2**

You can read about foreach's implicit type casting here:

http://www.dev102.com/2009/07/28/pay-attention-to-the-foreach-implicit-casting/

http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=1

And in the specification: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx

Scroll down to last section in 26.1

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot get useful information from your response.

Comment: My response answered exactly why they did as they did. If you do not understand the answer make a comment and ASK. Or edit your question to explain in more detail what you don't understand.

Comment: OK. So you mean separation is intended to implement a typed iterator? When I combine them as a single (see my code above after edit tag), I don't implement a typed iterator?

Comment: When you change to return a IEnumerator you get an object instead of an Person when iterating. The reason to why they use explicit interface implementation is to automatically get the typed enumerator when knowing that the list is of type People.

Comment: How about accepting the answer? I've shown you that I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can simply alter the code To:

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   {
      return new PeopleEnum(_people);
   }
```

OR  To:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
   return new PeopleEnum(_people);
}
```

Since, there the IEnumerable interface is being imherited, we cant omit the implementaion for GetEnumerator() method.

Comment: So what is the reason to separate them as the author did?

Comment: @xport - I've described why in my answer. The author is implementing a generic collection (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx), not the non-generic IEnumerable you provided in your msdn link.

Comment: My link is about non-generic IEnumerable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx

Comment: Reason to down vote: public PeopleEnum GetEnumerator() 
{ 
    return new PeopleEnum(_people); 
} 
cannot be compiled.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I didn't look at the sample, just assumed from the snippet you gave. You are correct that the additional method is not required here and is redundant, but it can be useful to return a strongly typed enumerator (rather than casting from object) - in the rare case that you would actually call GetEnumerator manually. The sample can also be made generic by simply adding the generic interface (The sample was probably written for the generic use and "downgraded" to be non-generic anyway).

Comment: Can you please have a look at the modified snipped above. If you feel that this is seeming to be fine, please don't forget upvote again!! :-)

Comment: @Mark, casting in the first code snippet (I have 2code snippets above), you think of it as a necessity? I can remove the casting, it still works.

Comment: @Siva, I don't know what you are doing. I don't ask the variant of my separation. OK. Anyway, I will up vote. :D

Comment: @xport = I mean casting from the POV of the consumer of your class. In the version which returns only the IEnumerable, the consumer would need to cast that back to a PeopleEnum, whereas that would not be necessary with the method which returns it strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Thats actually [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I know that. But, I am not talking about it. Thank you.